# What is the correct approach to have Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have two calls that will be based on request it could be single or both api calls at the same time, so i have implemented below code not sure if thats the correct approach to use promise.all , Also want to throw error back to user in case any promise failed.

`execute` function is executed from the routes.
if there is better way to implement i would appreciate the feedback.

main.ts

```
public async execute(@Request() request: express.Request): Promise<[any] | any> {
    if (request.body.lob === "credit") {
        return this.getCardDetails(request);
    }
    if (request.body.lob === "individual") {
        return this.getAccountDetails(request);
    }
    return Promise.all([this.getCardDetails(request), this.getAccountDetails(request)]);
}

@Post('getAccountDetails')
private async getAccountDetails(@Body() request: any): Promise<any> {
    // process retrieveData Call and get response 
}

@Post('getCardDetails')
private async getCardDetails(@Body() request: any): Promise<any> {

 // process cardDetails Call and get response 
}
```

Comment: `Promise.all` will throw the error if any of given promises fails. Implementation looks correct, what is the problem you are facing with this implementation?

Comment: This looks mostly fine, though I would place the `execute` stuff in the router that also writes the response directly, instead of having a method with a `Promise<[any] | any>` signature

Comment: thanks for the suggestion will fix that i was also looking if there is better way to write above code and error handling

Comment: `Promise<[any] | any>` should be `Promise<[any, any] | any>` I think as `all` will return a tuple with 2 elements in your case, or `Promise<any[] | any>` if you really want to return an arbitrary length array